# How to switch to a branch with different set of submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Git project is using Library A as a submodule mapped to a directory `library-a/`. Submodule configuration in `.gitmodule` is as follows. This is implemented in `main` branch and is pushed to the origin.

```
[submodule "library-a"]
        path = library-a
        url = https://.../example-library-a.git
```

I want to start working with replacing Library A with Library B that has improved and replacing features. I start by creating a new development branch to work in.

`$ git checkout -b develop`

First, remove Library A like in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules).

```
$ git rm library-a/

$ git status
On branch develop
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   .gitmodules
        deleted:    library-a

$ git commit -m "remove library a"
```

At this stage `cat .gitmodules` shows empty configuration.

Then, add replacing Library B, commit and push it to the origin.

```
$ git submodule add https://.../example-library-b.git library-b

$ git commit -m "add library b"

$ git push origin develop
```

Now the submodule configuration is correct for using Library B and it is mapped to a different folder than the previous library was. Everything is now pushed to the remote as well.

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "library-b"]
        path = library-b
        url = https://.../example-library-b.git
```

This configuration works locally and current branch can be switched between `main` and `develop` without problems. For example, the following switches current branch to `main` and updates submodules correctly so that Library A is present.

`$ git switch --recurse-submodules main`

However, branch switching does not work if the main project is cloned anywhere else, for example by another developer.

When the main project is cloned to a new location

```
$ git clone https://.../main-project.git --recurse-submodules

$ cd main-project/
```

branch switching results in the following error

```
$ git switch develop --recurse-submodules
fatal: not a git repository: ../.git/modules/library-b
fatal: could not reset submodule index
```

So how to switch to a branch that has different submodule configuration than the current branch?

Comment: Best solution so far seems to be switching `git switch develop` without `--recurse-submodules` option and then separately updating submodules using `git submodule sync` and `git submodule update`.